# ASP.NET Core Google Auth for multi-tenant apps with single callback url?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, asp.net-identity, google-oauth

I am building a multi-tenant asp.net core app based where tenants are selected by host names. So `tenant1.example.com`, `tenant2.example.com`, ..., and so on.

Also, I'm using Google authentication using the default Google auth handler in asp.net core `services.AddAuthentication(...).AddGoogle(...)`

It's working great, except that Google doesn't support wildcard callback URLs. So every time I add a new tenant, I have to configure my Google app with a new callback URL to reflect the new host: `tenant1.example.com/signin-google`, `tenant2.example.com`, ..., and so on.

The asp.net core Google handler lets you specify the callback path, but not the URL. I plan to overwrite the handler to have the callback URL always go to a redirector url hosted on the naked domain, `example.com/redirect-google` (I'll be careful about open redirects), and have that redirect to the appropriate sub-domain to complete the authentication.

Has anyone done this before? Anyone see a problem with this approach?

Comment: Seems like it'd work; are you going to rewrite it at the reverse proxy level? (Nginx?) I'd be worried about redirect attacks from tenant1 to tenant2; but maybe I'm over thinking it. Incidentally Stack Overflow uses stackauth -- a centralized site where authentication happens and then they redirect you back -- as if it's their own  OAuth provider.

Comment: We frequently go with a completely separate login application that interacts with the OAuth flow, then redirect to the actual application with an internal token once that has been negotiated.  I can't say that I've used it with a multitenant app, but that pattern has worked well for us in keeping our apps decoupled from the role/permission storage implementation.

Comment: I like the idea of a separate application, but that also adds complexity to hosting and deployment. Right now, I only have one app to worry about. I think eventually I'll have to add this other app, perhaps using IdentityServer4 Federation Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the authentication system does not allow you to further modify the host for the OAuth redirect URI. This is mostly done to make the system host name agnostic, which is a common pattern that is used throughout the framework (basically every URL generation is based on the current context).

As a workaround, what you could do is set up your own authentication handler for the Google scheme. You can actually inherit from the `GoogleHandler` and override the `BuildChallengeUrl`. That method is called to actually build the challenge URI of the authentication provider. It gets passed the `redirectUrl` which is the callback route of the OAuthHandler (the thing you cannot change the host name of).

So by overriding the method, you can simply change the `redirectUrl` that gets passed and replace it with the general URL that you want to use.

```cs
protected override string BuildChallengeUrl(AuthenticationProperties properties, string redirectUri)
{
    return base.BuildChallengeUrl(properties, "https://example.com/redirect-google");
}
```

When you do that, you will just have to replace the `GoogleHandler` in the DI config:

```cs
services.AddTransient<GoogleHandler, ReplacedGoogleHandler>();
```

Comment: I have modified redirect URL , its working fine. 

but how to return back to the original server after sign in with custom redirect url ?

Comment: Hi, How do I pass the current subdomain via the properties... can't access HttpContext

Comment: @Tushar If you’re inheriting from `GoogleHandler`, you can access the request object through the `Request` property.

Comment: Quick question: I tried setting the state value like this: properties.Items.Add("subdomain", "abc"); but the return state value in the return url is encrypted. How do I access that?

Comment: @Tushar It depends on _where_ you want to access the state. Usually, the properties will be unprotected back, e.g. into the `AuthenticationTicket` that is used in the authentication process.

Comment: @poke - Can I get them at IIS / Apache level so that I can redirect them to the respective domains based on the state value.. e.g. if I get state = abc, I can redirect it to abc.domain.com and so on... or if possible in a method in asp.net core...